# LESS: How to determine width: 15% of (100% - @SideBarWidth)

Tags: css, less

How do I calculate the width of a DIV that needs to be 15% of (100% - @SideBarWidth), where @SideBarWidth is the width of my side bar? To describe my question in another way, I am looking to get a percentage of the content area (excluding side bar area) of my page. Is this possible to calculate with CSS and LESS?

The LESS I have currently:

```
@sidebarWidth: 250px;

.myDiv
{
    position: fixed;
    left: @sidebarWidth;
    width: calc(15% * (100% - @sidebarWidth));
}
```

which when compiled is producing:

```
.myDiv
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: calc(-2250%);
}
```

with an undesired width of "calc(-2250%)".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bless%5d%20calc

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a decimal when multiplying

EDIT:
Sorry, you have to do the multiplication outside of the calculation

```
 width: calc(100% - @sidebarWidth) * .15;
```

Comment: This produces: width: 'calc(-22.5%);'